# Comparing multiple columns in Excel and remove dups

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns in Excel 2010 with email addresses, I need to be able to narrow all 3 columns to only have unique values. I don't necessarily need to merge the remaining values into a single column, but I definitely need to eliminate duplicates. I found another post that had a VB with it, but it didn't seem to work. It removed only a few duplicates:

```
Sub removeDuplicates()
Dim lastCol As Integer
lastCol = 5    'col 5 is column E

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim searchRange As Range
Set searchRange = wks.Range("A1:A" & wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

Dim compareArray As Variant
Dim searchArray As Variant

'Get all values from Col A to search against
compareArray = searchRange.Value

For col = lastCol - 1 To 1 Step -1
    'Set values to search for matches
    searchArray = searchRange.Offset(0, col - 1).Value

    'Set values to last column to compare against
    compareArray = searchRange.Offset(0, col).Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(compareArray)
        If compareArray(i, 1) = searchArray(i, 1) Then
            'Match found, delete and shift left
            Cells(i, col).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next i
 Next col
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are these three different lists of email addresses?  Could it be treated as a single list?

Comment: This seems like it would be pretty easy to solve without VBA.  Can you include a sample layout of the data that you're working with?

Comment: Well, the 3 columns represent the following. One column is of emails that have already been contacted, and the other two are from different lists. I need to find which emails from the two lists are in the 3rd column so they don't get emailed again. Am I going about this in the best way? Thanks!

Comment: A quick and dirty way to do this would be using the built in Filter feature (and select 'Unique records only' using the advanced option).  Once you have this list of uniques from your first column, copy and paste it into the next column.  Apply the same filter technique there, and then repeat once more in your third column.  This should work well as long as you only have to do this process once.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but it didn't seem to work. The problem is I need to remove any email addresses in column 2 and 3 that are also in column 1.

Comment: See my answer below.  I don't think I was clear enough on how to implement this in my previous comment as the unique results could be pasted over non-filtered results if the filters were not cleared each time (and you subsequently will lose your copy/paste ability with the selected items once clearing the filter).  Introducing temporary helper columns should resolve this.  Anyway, I went all the way through this is the attached screencast.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would propose doing this if it is a one-off task that you don't have to do very often.

Rather than typing out the entire process in detail, I have done a screencast of how I did this (and the entire process barely took me a minute to do).

**The quick overview:**

You will need to add a few temporary helper columns for unique values from each email list (one for each list), a 'merged list' column and then a final column.  Filter for the unique emails using the 'Advanced' filter option one column at a time.  Paste those values into the temporary column for that email list and then clear the filter.  Repeat until you have gone through each column and each temporary column has the unique values in it from each list.  Once you have the uniques from each list, paste these one at a time into the 'merged list' column (stacking the results in one long list) and then do a unique filter on that.  Copy/paste the uniques from that list into your final column, clear the filter, and you're done.

**Screencast is below:**

http://screencast.com/t/zL8VmUut

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since the first column are the ones you already contacted, swap the first column with the second and on the 3rd write a YES or NO value if email was found on the second column (the ones you already contacted).

Formula.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$11,1,FALSE)),"Not Contacted","Yes")
```

[image: Example]

As you can see, the one with Yes status is on the contacted list, you just filter the Not Contacted and you will have a new pending list in column A.
Simple.